# Evaluation on a basis of gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, gaussian-integral

Knowing that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx= \pi^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
Find:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} dx$$
And my question is how does this help if have the value of gaussian integral?

Comment: you mean $\pi^{1/2}$ not $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: You can solve this now with a simple $u$-substitution.

Comment: Hint: Try the substitution $\frac{x^2}{2} = u^2$ in your second integral.

Comment: A simple substitution $x/\sqrt{2}\to x$ suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $2=(\sqrt{2}\,)^2$; now make use of a $u$-substitution in the integral.

Comment: Thus the final result will be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\pi}$?

Comment: @mkropkowski Hint: $\sqrt{\pi}/\sqrt{\pi}=1$.

Comment: No; I'll let you work out the details. I've provided a hint.

Comment: answer $=1$? I forgot about $\sqrt{2}$ in the substitution

Comment: @mkropkowski: That is correct!

Answer (score 3):

Notice, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt \pi$$

Now, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2/2}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\left(x/\sqrt2\right)^2}dx$$

Let, $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}=t\implies \frac{x}{\sqrt 2}dx=dt\implies dx=\sqrt 2dt$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}\sqrt 2 dt$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$
Changing variable from $t$ to $x$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}(\sqrt \pi)=1$$